# Time difference query using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to take out difference between two times, first and second time using AM , PM 
I've columns:

```
FirstTime    SecondTime
10:14:42 PM  1:05:25 AM.
```

When i'm using DateDiff function it return wrong value and also i want access this in whole table not for single row and max is required on particular table

I've tried following queries:

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, first_time, second_time) AS 'Duration'  FROM tbl_weight

SELECT max (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, first_time, second_time)) AS 'Duration' , sr_no 
    FROM tbl_weight where first_weight != '0' and  second_weight != '0' group by sr_no  ;
```

but in both it return wrong value.

Comment: [It works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc7c0e99f3c508820fb59701cad9edbc). Please provide a good sample data and describe what's wrong with your queries.

Comment: What values are the statements returning for you and why do you think those values are wrong?

Comment: if i'm executing this --> select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '10:14:42 PM', '1:05:25 AM') AS 'Duration'  FROM table , it return =  -1269

Comment: @neelkamal That's true results, the start time should be less than second time, so you need to reverse the columns as I did in the db<>fiddle

Comment: if i reverse then i'll get wrong result for other value like in which AM , PM not involved and also i'll get wrong for max value.

Answer (score 0):

I just understand from the comments that you think `-1269` is wrong while it's not.

You need to reverse the order of the columns to get the desired results, because the `FirstTime` should be <= `SecondTime`. Or use `ABS()` function to get a positive number

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Minute, FirstTime, SecondTime) FirstWay,
       ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, SecondTime, FirstTime)) SecondWay
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('1:05:25 AM', '10:14:42 PM')
    --FirstTime should be < than SecondTime to get the desired outputs
    -- or use ABS() function to get positive number
) T(FirstTime, SecondTime)
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7abd9b927a9c7cd4fa6c2811432c57a7)

Comment: it return 1269 mins means 21.15 hours, but if you look at first and second time there is only difference of 2 hours and 50 mins. :)

Comment: Are you sure that the diff between `01:05:25` and `22:14:42` is 50 mn?

Comment: yes i'm 100% sure you can see first and second time and your db<>fiddle is return wrong answer. 
and this what my question is

Comment: one more thing this issue arise at when first time is PM and second time is AM. otherwise it working fine.

Comment: Since you're sure, could you please tell then what's the diff between `01:00:00` and `01:50:00` in minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression to reverse the `DATEDIFF` expression when the second time is before the first. This will provide the expected results when the second time is the following day.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN first_time < second_time 
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, first_time, second_time)
    ELSE
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, second_time, first_time)
    END AS Duration
FROM tbl_weight;
```

Comment: facing same issue when i execute query it gives me same -ve values.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116365/time-difference-query-using-ms-sql/62116417?noredirect=1#comment109861464_62116417) Dan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression :

```
select case when convert(datetime, firsttime) < convert(datetime, secondtime) 
            then dateadd(second, datediff(second, secondtime, firsttime), 0)
            else dateadd(second, datediff(second, firsttime, secondtime), 0)
       end
```